# Visual Studio - disable stepping into source code of module (Shouldly)

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, shouldly

I am using a an assertion framework called [Shouldly](https://github.com/shouldly/shouldly)  for C#.

The code looks like this:

```
[Fact]
public void SimpleTest()
{
    false.ShouldBe(true);
}
```

This is the same as:

```
[Fact]
public void SimpleTest()
{
    Assert.True(false);
}
```

However, when I debug the example that uses Shouldly, this happens:

[image]

But I want this to happen:

[image]

### The issue

When I debug with Shouldly, Visual Studio steps into the source code of the Shouldly package. I don't want to see the internals, I just want to see what line of the test my code broke on. I can use the Stack Trace to find what line my code broke on but this slows down my flow a lot.

I remember when I first started debugging with Shouldly, VS asked me if it should download the source files (`.pdb`?) of Shouldly to debug with, I think I accidentally told it yes.

If I look at the Modules I have loaded in VS, it shows me this:

[image]

It thinks Shouldly is "User Code" which is probably why it debugs into this. How can I disable this?

*I have this issue every time I change VS version. I've managed to fix it before but this time I can't figure it out.*

Comment: Last time you probably deleted the .pdb file from the c:\users\harve\ .nuget\packages\... directory.

Comment: Interesting. Before you posted this, I was deleting the whole `Shouldly` folder in my user directory but this wasn't helping. This time I deleted all references to `Shouldy.pdb` files in that directory, and it's fixed the issue. I've now found a proper fix, I'll add it to the answers!

Comment: Looks like the issue is documented here: https://github.com/shouldly/shouldly/issues/769

Answer (score 0):

You can disable symbol loading for a loaded module by:

1. opening the Module window
2. searching for the module you want to change
3. right clicking on it and disabling `Always Load Automatically`

[image]